# Variable not Defined in Python 3.5.1

Tags: python-3.x

I am a new coder with Python and I was wondering how I can fix this bug. Every time i put in the correct input in the code that I have, it spits out an error message, like so.

The code

```
total = 12
print ("I will play a game, you will choose 1, 2, or 3, and I will do the same, and I should always win, do you want to play?")
yesnoA = input("Yes or No?")
if yesnoA == yes:
    print ("Yay, your turn!")
    turnAA = input('Your First Move')
    if turnAA == 1:
        print ("I choose 3")
        total = total - 4
        print ("Total = ",total)
    else:
        if turnAA == 2:
            print ("I choose 2")
            total = total - 4
            print ("Total = ",total)
        else:
            if turnAA == 3:
                print ("I choose 1")
                total = total - 4
                print ("Total = ",total)
            else:
                print ("Cheater, try again")
else:
    yesnoB = input("Ok, you sure?")
    if yesnoB == yes:
        print ("Yay, your turn")
        turnAA = input('Your First Move')
        if turnAA == 1:
            print ("I choose 3")
            total = total - 4
            print ("Total = ",total)
        else:
            if turnAA == 2:
                print ("I choose 2")
                total = total - 4
                print ("Total = ",total)
            else:
                if turnAA == 3:
                    print ("I choose 1")
                    total = total - 4
                    print ("Total = ",total)
                else:
                    print ("Cheater, try again")
    else:
        print ("Well, goodbye")
```

The Output

```
Yes or No?yes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/*user*/Desktop/Code/Python/Nim Game.py", line 5, in <module>
    if yesnoA == yes:
NameError: name 'yes' is not defined
```

This is in version 3.5.1

Comment: You should accept the answer that you found most helpful. Accepting answer gives you reps too!

Answer (score 2):

You need to either declare a variable `yes` with a value `'yes'`, or compare your variable `yesnoA` with a string `'yes'`. Maybe something like this:

```
if yesnoA.lower() == 'yes': # using lower(), so that user's input is case insensitive
    # do the rest of your work
```

Your code afterwards has some more issues. I will give you a clue. [`input`](http://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#input) always returns the user's input as string. So if you need integer from user, you will have to convert the user input into integer using [`int(your_int_as_string)`](http://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#int) like so:

```
turnAA = int(input('Your First Move'))
# turnAA is now an integer, provided the user entered valid integer value
```

---

Your take from this question on SO:

- Look at the Traceback. It says clearly which line the error is in, and also what the error is. In your case it is `NameError`
- Take a look at docs for [`NameError`](http://docs.python.org/3.5/library/exceptions.html#NameError)
- Study [this tutorial](http://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/errors.html?highlight=nameerror#exceptions). It will help you get used to with some basic errors commonly encountered.

Comment: This is much better than the answer I proposed, forgot about the `.lower()` method haha

Answer (score 1):

You have not defined the variable `yes`. You should do something like:

```
yes = "Yes"
```

At the start of the code

Comment: No, I meant for him to define the variable if he wants, like when in C++ you define a macro. Just so that he has a "constant" comparison variable to the string "yes"

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to compare `yesnoA` to a variable named `yes`, which, indeed was not defined, instead of the string literal `'yes'` (note the quotes!). Add the quotes and you should be fine:

```
if yesnoA == 'yes':
    # Here --^---^
```